# Expand 2D array to Tree Layout

Tags: json, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a two-dimensional array which, right now, looks something like this (sample data, not the actual fields):

```
[
    ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val1" ,"key3": "val1"],
    ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val1" ,"key3": "val2"],
    ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val2" ,"key3": "val3"],
    ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val2" ,"key3": "val4"],
    ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val3" ,"key3": "val5"],
    ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val3" ,"key3": "val6"],
    ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val4" ,"key3": "val7"],
    ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val4" ,"key3": "val8"]
]
```

The data basically branches out as the array gets deeper, and I'd like to create an algorithm that can parse this into a format that's better suited for this type of data, specifically a tree.

This is what I'd like the result to look like:

```
{
    "key1": [
        {"val1": [
            {"key2": [
                {"val1": [
                    {"key3": "val1"},
                    {"key3": "val2"}
                ]},
                {"val2": [
                    {"key3": "val3"},
                    {"key3": "val4"}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]},
        {"val2": [
            {"key2": [
                {"val3": [
                    {"key3": "val5"},
                    {"key3": "val6"}
                ]},
                {"val4": [
                    {"key3": "val7"},
                    {"key3": "val8"}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]
}
```

Could someone point me in the general direction of doing something like this? Or is there a better way to sort this type of data? Thanks!

Edit: I'd like to add that the depth is dynamic, meaning that there's not a set amount of key/value pairs in each row. The data also could branch to more than two different key/value pairs. For example, a key could have five different values that have three different keys under them.

Comment: is this a homework or a real life application? it shouldnt be difficult to work it out as json is so common around the web, several handy libraries in common languages like python and php support to parse and prettify it.

Comment: This is a real-life application. I'm actually doing this in Swift and storing the data in a dictionary, but I just used JSON and a general array to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: i have noticed that your expected result has a different structure from your input... Can you briefly describe your logic to convert it, and how would you like to use the new object created after sorting?

Comment: The original input is actually coming from a program that exports pivot tables to CSV files (which are two-dimensional). Basically, I want to group up all the key/value pairs with the same "parent", for every level on the array. This result will be used to generate pivot table in another program.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work.  It goes through and organizes the input into a deeply nested array, then picks that array apart into the tree you're looking for.

```
var twoDimArray = [
        ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val1" ,"key3": "val1"],
        ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val1" ,"key3": "val2"],
        ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val2" ,"key3": "val3"],
        ["key1": "val1" ,"key2": "val2" ,"key3": "val4"],
        ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val3" ,"key3": "val5"],
        ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val3" ,"key3": "val6"],
        ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val4" ,"key3": "val7"],
        ["key1": "val2" ,"key2": "val4" ,"key3": "val8"]
    ]

    var arrayOfKeys = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

    var combinedArray: Array<String> = []
    for dict in twoDimArray {
        for key in arrayOfKeys {
            combinedArray.append(key)
            combinedArray.append(dict[key]!)
        }
    }

    print(combinedArray)

    for var index = 0; index < combinedArray.count - 2; index = index + 2 {
        let key = combinedArray[index]
        let value = combinedArray[index + 1]
        if combinedArray.count == 2 || combinedArray.count % 2 == 1 {
            break
        }
        let start = index + 2
        for var index2 = start; index2 < combinedArray.count; index2 = index2 + 2 {
            let key2 = combinedArray[index2]
            let value2 = combinedArray[index2 + 1]
            if key == key2 && value == value2 {
                combinedArray.removeAtIndex(index2)
                combinedArray.removeAtIndex(index2)
            }
        }
    }

    var doubledArray: Array<Array<String>> = []

    for var index = 0; index < combinedArray.count; index = index + 2 {
        doubledArray.append([combinedArray[index], combinedArray[index+1]])
    }

    var result: Array<Array<Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>> = []
    var currentKey = arrayOfKeys.first!
    var currentArray: Array<Array<Dictionary<String, String>>> = []

    var index2 = 0
    for var index = 0; index < arrayOfKeys.count; index++ {
        currentArray = []
        currentKey = arrayOfKeys[index]

        var lastFind = -2
        var tempArray: Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = []
        for var index3 = 0; index3 < doubledArray.count; index3++ {
            var arr = doubledArray[index3]
            if arr[0] == currentKey {
                lastFind = index3
                tempArray.append([arr[0]:arr[1]])
                if index3 == doubledArray.count - 1 {
                    currentArray.append((tempArray as NSArray).copy() as! Array<Dictionary<String, String>>)
                }
            }
            else if lastFind == index3 - 1 {
                currentArray.append((tempArray as NSArray).copy() as! Array<Dictionary<String, String>>)
                tempArray = []
            }
        }

        result.append(currentArray)
        index2++
    }
    print(result)

    var arrayTree: Array<Array<Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>>
    var resultTree = NSDictionary()
    var v: AnyObject = []

    class Tree: NSObject {
        var value: String = ""
        var elements: AnyObject = []

        func convertToDictionary() -> NSDictionary {
            var values: Array<NSDictionary> = []

            for item in self.elements as! NSArray {
                if item is Tree {
                    values.append((item as! Tree).convertToDictionary())
                }
                else {
                    values.append(item as! NSDictionary)
                }
            }

            return [value:elements]
        }
    }


    func createElementsForTree(input: Array<Array<Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>>) -> Tree {
        var trees: Array<Tree> = []

        for var index = 0; index < result[result.count - 1].count; index++ {
            let array = result[result.count - 1][index]
            let secondIndex = Int(ceil(Float(index)/2))
            let value = result[result.count - 2][secondIndex]

            let newTree = Tree()
            newTree.value = (value[0] as NSDictionary).allValues[0] as! String
            newTree.elements = array
            trees.append(newTree)
        }
        print(trees)
        var isKey = true
        for var reverseIndex = result.count - 2; reverseIndex >= 0;  {
            for var index = 0; index < result[reverseIndex].count; index++ {
                let arr = result[reverseIndex][index]
                let tree = Tree()
                if isKey {
                    tree.value = (arr.first! as NSDictionary).allKeys[0] as! String
                    var elements = [trees.removeFirst()]
                    if reverseIndex != result.count - 2 {
                        elements.append(trees.removeFirst())
                    }
                    tree.elements = elements
                    trees.append(tree)
                }
                else {
                    tree.value = (arr.first! as NSDictionary).allValues[0] as! String
                    tree.elements = [trees.removeFirst()]
                    trees.append(tree)
                }
            }
            if isKey {
                reverseIndex--
                isKey = false
            }
            else {
                isKey = true
            }
        }

        let tree = Tree()
        tree.value = (result[0][0][0] as NSDictionary).allKeys[0] as! String
        tree.elements = trees
        return tree
    }

    let objectTree = createElementsForTree(result)

    let finalResult = objectTree.convertToDictionary()

    print(finalResult)
```